# active admin collection_select and passing to controller override create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have list dropdown list in my activeadmin that populates the recipe and menu. I'm trying to override the create method but it is not working

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @menu_recipe] do |f| %>

<p>
 <%= f.collection_select :recipe_id,
  Recipe.all,:id,:name,:prompt => true%>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.collection_select :menu_id,
  Menu.all,:id,:name,:prompt => true%>
</p>   
<%= f.buttons :commit %>
<%end%>
```

Whenever I try to catch the and create or group it, it returns with a `Couldn't find Recipe without an ID error`

my active admin controller which i override is

```
ActiveAdmin.register MenuRecipe do
    menu :parent => "Manage Package"

   form :partial => "menu_recipe"

    controller do
      def new
        new! do |format|
          @menu_recipe = MenuRecipe.new  
        end
      end

      def create
        create! do |format|
          recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])
          menu = Menu.find(params[:menu_id])
          @menu_recipe = @menu.add_recipe(menu.id)

          if @menu_recipe.save
            redirect_to {admin_menu_recipe_url}
          end
        end  
      end
    end

end
```

im i doing it right? if anything is needed please just ask thanks in advance

Comment: One time you use `menu` another time you use `@menu` in `create` method. Maybe this is a problem?

Comment: @GrzegorzŁuszczek even i change the  `menu = Menu.find(params[:menu_id])` to  `@menu = Menu.find(params[:menu_id])` still same :(

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it's how you are getting the recipe_id.  I would maybe debug the params and see what the actual values are.

You may need to do something like this:

```
params[:menu_recipe][recipe_id]
```